# Как сохранять результаты в файл по кнопке?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Задача такая: Весь день я "тыкаю" <kbd>+0,1</kbd> и <kbd>+0,2</kbd>, а в конце дня хочу сохранить результат в файл.

В идеале, если это будет постоянный файл с результатами за каждый день. Что должно храниться: дата и рядом с ней результат. Например:

```
27.02.2021 9,5

28.02.2021 8,9

29.02.2021 9,7
```

Как это реализовать?

Что сейчас имеем:

```js
let add = document.getElementById('increment');
let remove = document.getElementById('decrement');

let add2 = document.getElementById('increment2');
let remove2 = document.getElementById('decrement2');

let int = document.getElementById('number');
let integer = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  integer += 0.1;
  int.innerHTML = integer;
})

remove.addEventListener('click', function() {
  integer -= 0.1;
  int.innerHTML = integer;
})

add2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  integer += 0.2;
  int.innerHTML = integer;
})

remove2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  integer -= 0.2;
  int.innerHTML = integer;
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333232;
}

#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 10px solid #FFA500;
  margin: 50px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #88B169;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font: 2em "Calibri", sans-serif;
}

#number {
  height: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}

#increment2 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#increment {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#decrement {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#decrement2 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF=8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title> Счетчик УП </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Счетчик УП</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="number">0</div>
    <button id="increment2">+ 0,2</button><button id="increment">+ 0,1</button><button id="decrement">- 0,1</button><button id="decrement2">- 0,2</button>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1. Работать с файлами из JS нельзя - политика безопасности. Можно генерировать файл, но отдавать его на сохранение, т.е. все равно юзер должен сам выбрать куда и как его сохранять. При записи, естественно, все перезатираем.

2. Можно посмотреть в сторону localStorage, и хранить данные там.

3. Заюзать бэкенд (php, nodeJs, еще что-то по желанию). Отправлять данные на бэкенд, а там их обрабатывать и сохранять хоть в файлы, хоть в базу.

Comment: node.js или php - а сам js не умеет работать с файловой системой